# What rig or custom components would help record 360 degrees of stereo audio, not unlike human ears in a theatre

Tags: audio-recording, theatre-sound-design, nature-recording, stage

I'm interested in recording sound in 360 degrees, and then playing back 180 degrees (or similar to human ears) for an immersive Sound Therapy program for holistic health.

Are you aware of any way to record sound in 360 degrees?, so that I can listen as if I was standing in the middle of the Amazon forest, and without video, sound only, I could hear what's around me.

Hardware ideas or suggestions (as to what kind of microphone(s) needed in a stack/array) would be helpful as well.

Comment: [What is Binaural Audio?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/46462/what-is-binaural-audio)

Answer (score 1):

The [Neumann KU-100](https://en-de.neumann.com/ku-100) is designed specifically for binaural recording and testing. It requires post-processing after recording, but is as close to "standard" as things seem to get in this area.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways of recording 360 degree audio, binaural is probably the most common for for example VR/AR (usually 'headlocked', meaning the sounds stay in the same place relative to head movement), ambisonics is another way to do it. In each category there are many different possible options of recording it with each their own specific gear. I found this to be a helpful guide: https://training.npr.org/2018/11/27/360-audio/